# ' variable' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm new to Arduino coding and I'm not sure what issue I'm having with displaying the variable as serialPrint. Here is part of my code:

```
void loop() 
{
  int force1raw = analogRead(FSR_PIN1);
  int force2raw = analogRead(FSR_PIN2);
  int force3raw = analogRead(FSR_PIN3);
  float force1 = force1raw;
  float force2 = force2raw;
  float force3 = force3raw;

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    // Use ADC reading to calculate voltage:
    float f1v = force1 * VCC / 1023.0;
    // Use voltage and static resistor value to 
    // calculate FSR resistance:
    float f1r = R_DIV * (VCC / f1v - 1.0);
  }
    Serial.println("Resistance 1: " + String(f1r) + " ohms");
    // Estimate force based on slopes in figure 3 of
    // FSR datasheet:
    float force;
    float f1g = 1.0 / f1r; // Calculate conductance
    // Break parabolic curve down into two linear slopes:
    if (f1g <= 600) 
      force1f = (f1g - 0.00075) / 0.00000032639;
    else
      force1f =  f1g / 0.000000642857;
    Serial.println("Force 1: " + String(force2f) + " g");
    Serial.println();

    delay(100);
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to provide the full error message and the line it is reported on.

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes?

Comment: @BobMorane Because it's a terrible post, perhaps? Closing it is presumably better and fairer than downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

```
Serial.println("Resistance 1: " + String(f1r) + " ohms");
```

it uses the variable `f1r` whose scope just ended.

In C++, when a variable is defined inside a scope (between some `{` and `}`), it does not exist outside of it.